# Rating bar shows half star despite setting step to 1

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am adding dynamically a rating bar to a custom component. I am receiving the rating from a server, and initially, it is showing ok. But, if for example, I receive a 5 stars rating, if I click on the second star, stars 3 4 and 5 are drawn like receiving half star each, what makes no sense to me. If I receive 0 stars from the server, modifying works ok, and stars are drawn perfectly, if I receive 2 stars from the server, stars 3 4 and 5 works ok, but stars 1 and 2 are drawn like receiving half star each...

The XML of the rating bar is like this:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventsubtitle"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:max="5"/>
```

And the code of the RatingBar:

```
ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
            if(!agenda.getRating().equals("null") && !agenda.getRating().equals("") && agenda.getRating()!=null){
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(agenda.getRating()));
            }else{
                ratingBar.setRating(0F);
            }

            ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    Log.i("David", "sending rating: "+rating);//This shows an x.0 value always
                    float ratingToSet=(float) Math.ceil(rating);
                    Log.i("David", "rating: "+ratingToSet);//This shows an x.0 value always
                    ratingBar.setRating(ratingToSet);
                    //rating sent to server
            });
```

Anybody can help me? Thank you.

EDIT: Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT 2: Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timein"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timeout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timein"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timein"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eventtitle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/timein"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eventsubtitle"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eventtitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventtitle"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventsubtitle"
    android:stepSize="1.0"/>



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/verticalline"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/timein"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/speakerrl"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/speakerrl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeout"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/speaker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/speakersubtitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/speaker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/speaker"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/askbutton"
    android:text="@string/askquestion"
    android:layout_below="@+id/speakerrl"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/askbutton"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its a shame I had to look for a third rating bar library in order to get this working properly...

Answer (score 1):

Add max rating programmatically , It should fix the issue

```
ratingBar.setMax(5);
```

**Edit:**

replace your rating bar with and check

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventsubtitle">

    <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
            android:stepSize="1.0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No difference, If I receive 5 star rating from server, and modify it to 2 stars, for example, stars 3 4 and 5 looks like each star receives half stars, as shown in screenshot.

Comment: can you add complete layout ?

Comment: I am adding the complete layout to the question. Its a layout that is added to a LinearLayout inside another layout, which is added to a ViewFlipper...

Comment: ok for rating bar add another parent linear layout and keep nothing else except rating bar in it and check

Comment: No luck, behaviour is the same.

Comment: did you fix the height too to 45dp ?

Comment: Yes, didn't fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189676/discussion-between-manohar-reddy-and-fustigador).

Answer (score 0):

ratingBar.setStepSize(1f); worked for me